# starting alphad what is the correct rpcconnectport

Tags: sidechains

following the instructions in the [alpha-README.md](https://github.com/ElementsProject/elements/blob/alpha/alpha-README.md) file on [GitHub](https://github.com/ElementsProject/elements)
in step number 2, to start alphad it is suggested to do:

```
./alphad -rpcuser=$RPC_USER -rpcpassword=$RPC_PASS -testnet -rpcconnect=127.0.0.1 -rpcconnectport=18332 -tracksidechain=all -txindex -blindtrust=true -daemon
```

my question is about the rpcconnectport=18332
**why 18332 instead of 4241?**  like in step 5

Answer (score 1):

Because in order to validate sidechain transfers, `alphad` needs to connect to a testnet `bitcoind`. The rpcconnect-like flags passed to it are information about how it can do that, so you need to use the running `bitcoind`'s port.